# ¿Por qué imprime dos veces durante la validación en JAVA?

Tags: java

Soy novato en **JAVA** y me gustaría saber porqué imprime dos veces `("ingresar hora válida")`, si ingreso un valor que no corresponde **(900 por ejemplo)**

A continuación expongo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ej68_ultimo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hora;
        int continuanMasClientes;
        boolean sigue = false;

        ClienteEstacionamiento cliente = new ClienteEstacionamiento();
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner opcion = new Scanner(System.in);
        int continua;

        // Ingreso de horas
        do
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese horas: ");
                hora = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

                if( cliente.esHoraValida(hora) == true )
                    cliente.ingresarHoras(hora);
            }
            while( cliente.esHoraValida(hora) == false );

            System.out.printf("Horas en el estacionamiento: %d, cobro correspondiente: %f\n", cliente.obtenerHoras(), cliente.calcularCargos());

            System.out.println("mas clientes? 1(si), 2(no): ");
            continua = Integer.parseInt(opcion.nextLine());             
        }
        while( continua == 1 );

    }

}
```

Y la clase "ClienteEstacionamiento" es la siguiente:

```
public class ClienteEstacionamiento {

    private int horasEstadia;
    private final static double COBROADICIONAL = 0.5;
    private final static double COBROMAXIMO = 10.0;

    public void ingresarHoras(int hrs)
    {
            horasEstadia = hrs;
    }

    public boolean esHoraValida(int hrs)
    {
        boolean esHoraCorrecta;

        if( (hrs < 1) || (hrs >= 90) )
        {
            System.out.println("Ingresar hora válida");
            esHoraCorrecta = false;
        }
        else
        {
            esHoraCorrecta = true;
        }

        return esHoraCorrecta;
    }

    public int obtenerHoras()
    {
        return horasEstadia;
    }

    public double calcularCargos()
    {
        double cobro;
        double diferenciaHoras;

        if( horasEstadia <= 3 )
            cobro = 2.0;            
        else
        {
            if ( horasEstadia >= 10)
                cobro = COBROMAXIMO;
            else
            {
                diferenciaHoras = horasEstadia - 3;
                cobro = 2 + ( diferenciaHoras * COBROADICIONAL );
            }
        }

        return cobro;

    }
}
```

Comment: Pienso que es mejor utilizar la opción while. Por otro lado, no es una buena práctica hacer que un método sea responsable de diferentes funciones (en tu caso pedir hora y verificar que sea válida), además se presta a confusión(esHoraValida solo hace referencia a una función ). El dia que retomes el código después de un tiempo sin recisarlo veras que resulta difícil de seguir y que parte de código es encargada de las diferentes funciones.

Comment: ¡Gracias por atender mi pregunta David!
Siguiendo tu comentario, he leído en libros de JAVA que se debe atomizar los métodos (hacer que hagan una sola cosa), por ejemplo, hay situaciones que se hace difícil poner un nombre a los métodos y eso se debe a que hacen varias cosas a las vez, esto ayuda a futuro a depurar el código. Intenté aplicar esto pero al parecer no fue bien hecho.
Creo que no logro entender bien lo que tu me enseñas. 
Atento a tu sugerencia. Mil gracias.

Comment: Por otro lado, sobre la instrucción 'while' lo aplicaré, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tal vez sea por que mandas a llamar dos veces el método *cliente.esHoraValida(hora)* :

```
  do
    {
        System.out.println("Ingrese horas: ");
        hora = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        if( cliente.esHoraValida(hora) == true ) // uno aquí
            cliente.ingresarHoras(hora);
    }
    while( cliente.esHoraValida(hora) == false ); /// y el segundo aquí
```

Lo ideal seria que iguales a una variable y después sea la variable la que evaluas como lo haces con "continua"

Comment: Mil gracias, todo muy claro.